# JOptionPane not displaying and code doesn't proceed

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have been trying to build a simple java application which simulates bank deposits and withdrawals. 
I tried to use the JOptionPane to show an error if the user tries to withdraw more than the bank account balance. But the JOptionPane does not display the message and the code does not proceed to the next line.

My Bank class which contains the main application

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bank {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
        //Define an object of type Scanner to get the input
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String name; //Local variable to get the name
        double bal; //Local variable to get the balance


        //Getting the inputs from the user
        System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
        name = inp.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the balance: ");
        bal = inp.nextDouble();
        Account a1 = new Account(name, bal); //Creating Account object a1


        inp.nextLine();
        /**The above command is to remove the newline character after 
           inp.nextDouble() since it is not consumed by it and this affects 
           the string input in the following lines*/

        System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
        name = inp.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the balance: ");
        bal = inp.nextDouble();
        Account a2 = new Account(name, bal); //Creating Account object a2

        //Displaying the input details
        a1.dispDetails();
        a2.dispDetails();

        /**For this app we just withdraw money from a1 and deposit in a2 */

        System.out.println("Enter the amount to be withdrawn from a1");
        double w_d = inp.nextDouble();
        a1.withdraw(w_d);
        a1.dispDetails();


        System.out.println("Enter the amount to be deposited in a2: ");
        double deposit = inp.nextDouble();
        a2.credit(deposit);
        a2.dispDetails();

        System.out.println( "Number of accounts created is "+Account.getCount());
        }

}
```

My Account class in which the JOptionPane is not working

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Account {
/** Declaration of the class variables*/
private final String name; //store the name of the account holder
private double balance;//store the balance
private final int acc_num; //since account number is not changed, set as final
static int count = 0; //to keep track of the number of accounts
JFrame f = new JFrame();

public Account(String n,double bal) 
{
    count++; 
    this.name = n;
    //generating a random account number based on count
    this.acc_num = count*599*254715; 
    this.balance = bal;

}
/** static function to access the static variable*/
static int getCount()
{
    return count;
}

/** To deduct amount on withdrawal Raises a warning if there is 
    insufficient balance*/           
public void withdraw (double amt)
{
    if(amt < balance)
        balance -= amt;
    else
    {    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Insufficient Balance");//not working


    }    
}


//credit an amount to the account
public void credit (double amt)
{
    balance += amt;
}

//display the details of the account
public void dispDetails()
{
System.out.println("Name: "+name+"\nAccount number: "+acc_num);
System.out.println("Balance= "+balance+"\n");
}



}
```

It does not get any input or stop running after the JOptionPane line.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Try using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient Balance");` - possibly the non-existent frame is causing issues

Comment: So, I tried your code.  I removed `f` (completely) and was able to see the `JOptionPane` popup, but in my testing it appeared behind my IDE

Comment: @Ish updated my answer - should be fixed now

Comment: @MadProgrammer, This was the problem I too had. Thanks. But is there any way to make it visible on top of the IDE and not behind?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the AWT-Thread and how the shutdown happens (it needs at least one active window it seems). I fixed it by creating an invisible `JFrame` which somehow doesn't let the AWT-Threads end. Just put this as the first statements in your `main`:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setVisible(true);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> f.setVisible(false));
```

and your `JOptionPane` will work.

Comment: I my (limited) testing, it didn't seem to make a difference if the frame was visible or not or if `null` was supplied instead

Comment: @Halko Karr-Sajtarevic the Message window still appears behind my IDE and the JOptionPane closes but still, the program does not terminate after it ends. The final part "number of accounts" is printed to the console but the program does not terminate.